# SwiperJS progress bar, how to fill it in a correct duration according to data-swiper-autoplay property?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I have this pin of swiper js https://codepen.io/yassersharaf/pen/qBJoWGY

The problem here is the progress bar color fill is fixed by CSS in 2 seconds. I want the progress bar to be filled according to the value of the data-swiper-autoplay property of th current slide. Here's the current CSS code

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active::before {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: slide-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.3, 1) forwards;
  animation: slide-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.3, 1) forwards;
}
```

How to change this value to match every slide data-swiper-autoplay property?